# Can't Center Nav Div

Tags: wordpress, navigation, centering

Okay, so I've looked at various posts on StackOverflow addressing the problem of centering a nav div. The solution seems to be:

```
.menu {
  text-align: center;
}
```

But no matter what div wrapping around the nav I use this on it does nothing. You can see the problem at http://www.dustinlee.co

I'm using this framework: https://github.com/jbckmn/naked-wordpress

Notice the navigation is on the left hand side. Even more strange, when you resize the window it begins to almost to the center.

Adding even more to my confusion is the fact that it's wrapped in this:

```
<nav class="site-navigation main-navigation">
```

Which seems to be associated with nothing in the styles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this to your css

```
header nav ul{display:inline-block;}
```

Comment: Wow, this worked. I would have never thought of this. Would you mind briefly explaining how you came to this conclusion? Thank you for the help, I appreciate it!

Comment: This is working well accept at 490px screen width and below. Then it begins moving a bit to the left.

Comment: the default browser setting for a ul is display:block - which makes it impossible to center with a text align.
inline-block - makes it a block as well as displaying in a line.
see - http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp

Comment: @DustinLee when it goes belowe 490 add a media query and take float:left off the li